# SCCM client error after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows, upgrade, sccm

I've upgraded the Windows 10 to 1809 for test purposes and now the SCCM client has the problem that it needs a very long time until it starts and then aborts with the error:

```
Loading Software Center returned error code 0x80041001 (-2147217407).
```

Unfortunately I do not really find much under the error message, are there any solutions for that?

If I reset the Windows installation and then install the SCCM client everything works fine again ...

System information:

- Version 1810
- Console version: 5.1810.1075.2000
- Site version: 5.0.8740.1000

Answer (score 0):

Small addendum, after I did the following everything seems to work again:

1. SCCM Upgrade
2. SCCM client deinstallation
3. WMIRepair (Roger Zander)
4. Reinstall SCCM client